# jqPlot axis label angle and font-size

Tags: jqplot

I'm using angled labels on my jqPlot bar charts to allow me to fit more bars onto a page.  I'm having issues with using the font-size property in conjunction with the angle property.

My tick options for my xaxis are as follows:

```
tickOptions: {
    angle: -90,
    font-size: '10pt'
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the font size doesn't appear to have the expected bearing on the font size of the labels.  My charts dynamically resize with changes in screen size and on small screens the label font is rendered very small and on large screens the font is giant.  If you resize a screen you will see the font size of the angled labels changing.

Changing the font-size appears to affect the size that the font is rendered at internally, such that a large font size gives a sharp font and a small font size gives a fuzzy font.  What it doesn't do is affect the size of the font on screen.

Is there any way to fix the font size for angled labels on charts that change size dynamically with the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper answer to my question.  I ended up changing the charts where I have a lot of bars to a line chart and using intermittent labels for the wide captions.

Used @Artholl answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18656405/410928 for the intermittent labels.