# jqplot - show only desired ticks on x-axis

Tags: javascript, graph, jqplot, linechart

My plot (always) contains 672 points [image]

I would like my plot to show only some of the ticks (30th and others which position % 50 equals 0):

```
xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: res.ticks,
                label: (res.xAxisLabel !== undefined) ? res.xAxisLabel : '',
                labelOptions: {
                    textColor: '#000000',
                    fontFamily: 'Arial'
                },
                tickOptions: {
                    showGridline: false,
                    angle: (res.xAxisTickAngle !== undefined) ? res.xAxisTickAngle : 0,
                    textColor: '#000000',
                    fontFamily: 'Arial'
                },
                tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer
            }
```

`res.ticks` is what comes as a AJAX response:

```
[[0,"0"],[1,""],[2,""],[3,""],[4,""],[5,""],[6,""],[7,""],[8,""],[9,""],[10,""],[11,""],[12,""],[13,""],[14,""],[15,""],[16,""],[17,""],[18,""],[19,""],[20,""],[21,""],[22,""],[23,""],[24,""],[25,""],[26,""],[27,""],[28,""],[29,""],[30,"30"],[31,""],[32,""],[33,""],[34,""],[35,""],[36,""],[37,""],[38,""],[39,""],[40,""],[41,""],[42,""],[43,""],[44,""],[45,""],[46,""],[47,""],[48,""],[49,""],[50,"50"],[51,""],[52,""],[53,""],[54,""],[55,""],[56,""],[57,""],[58,""],[59,""],[60,""],[61,""],[62,""],[63,""],[64,""],[65,""],[66,""],[67,""],[68,""],[69,""],[70,""],[71,""],[72,""],[73,""],[74,""],[75,""],[76,""],[77,""],[78,""],[79,""],[80,""],[81,""],[82,""],[83,""],[84,""],[85,""],[86,""],[87,""],[88,""],[89,""],[90,""],[91,""],[92,""],[93,""],[94,""],[95,""],[96,""],[97,""],[98,""],[99,""],[100,"100"],[101,""],[102,""],[103,""],[104,""],[105,""],[106,""],[107,""],[108,""],[109,""],[110,""],[111,""],[112,""],[113,""],[114,""],[115,""],[116,""],[117,""],[118,""],[119,""],[120,""],[121,""],[122,""],[123,""],[124,""],[125,""],[126,""],[127,""],[128,""],[129,""],[130,""],[131,""],[132,""],[133,""],[134,""],[135,""],[136,""],[137,""],[138,""],[139,""],[140,""],[141,""],[142,""],[143,""],[144,""],[145,""],[146,""],[147,""],[148,""],[149,""],[150,"150"],[151,""],[152,""],[153,""],[154,""],[155,""],[156,""],[157,""],[158,""],[159,""],[160,""],[161,""],[162,""],[163,""],[164,""],[165,""],[166,""],[167,""],[168,""],[169,""],[170,""],[171,""],[172,""],[173,""],[174,""],[175,""],[176,""],[177,""],[178,""],[179,""],[180,""],[181,""],[182,""],[183,""],[184,""],[185,""],[186,""],[187,""],[188,""],[189,""],[190,""],[191,""],[192,""],[193,""],[194,""],[195,""],[196,""],[197,""],[198,""],[199,""],[200,"200"],[201,""],[202,""],[203,""],[204,""],[205,""],[206,""],[207,""],[208,""],[209,""],[210,""],[211,""],[212,""],[213,""],[214,""],[215,""],[216,""],[217,""],[218,""],[219,""],[220,""],[221,""],[222,""],[223,""],[224,""],[225,""],[226,""],[227,""],[228,""],[229,""],[230,""],[231,""],[232,""],[233,""],[234,""],[235,""],[236,""],[237,""],[238,""],[239,""],[240,""],[241,""],[242,""],[243,""],[244,""],[245,""],[246,""],[247,""],[248,""],[249,""],[250,"250"],[251,""],[252,""],[253,""],[254,""],[255,""],[256,""],[257,""],[258,""],[259,""],[260,""],[261,""],[262,""],[263,""],[264,""],[265,""],[266,""],[267,""],[268,""],[269,""],[270,""],[271,""],[272,""],[273,""],[274,""],[275,""],[276,""],[277,""],[278,""],[279,""],[280,""],[281,""],[282,""],[283,""],[284,""],[285,""],[286,""],[287,""],[288,""],[289,""],[290,""],[291,""],[292,""],[293,""],[294,""],[295,""],[296,""],[297,""],[298,""],[299,""],[300,"300"],[301,""],[302,""],[303,""],[304,""],[305,""],[306,""],[307,""],[308,""],[309,""],[310,""],[311,""],[312,""],[313,""],[314,""],[315,""],[316,""],[317,""],[318,""],[319,""],[320,""],[321,""],[322,""],[323,""],[324,""],[325,""],[326,""],[327,""],[328,""],[329,""],[330,""],[331,""],[332,""],[333,""],[334,""],[335,""],[336,""],[337,""],[338,""],[339,""],[340,""],[341,""],[342,""],[343,""],[344,""],[345,""],[346,""],[347,""],[348,""],[349,""],[350,"350"],[351,""],[352,""],[353,""],[354,""],[355,""],[356,""],[357,""],[358,""],[359,""],[360,""],[361,""],[362,""],[363,""],[364,""],[365,""],[366,""],[367,""],[368,""],[369,""],[370,""],[371,""],[372,""],[373,""],[374,""],[375,""],[376,""],[377,""],[378,""],[379,""],[380,""],[381,""],[382,""],[383,""],[384,""],[385,""],[386,""],[387,""],[388,""],[389,""],[390,""],[391,""],[392,""],[393,""],[394,""],[395,""],[396,""],[397,""],[398,""],[399,""],[400,"400"],[401,""],[402,""],[403,""],[404,""],[405,""],[406,""],[407,""],[408,""],[409,""],[410,""],[411,""],[412,""],[413,""],[414,""],[415,""],[416,""],[417,""],[418,""],[419,""],[420,""],[421,""],[422,""],[423,""],[424,""],[425,""],[426,""],[427,""],[428,""],[429,""],[430,""],[431,""],[432,""],[433,""],[434,""],[435,""],[436,""],[437,""],[438,""],[439,""],[440,""],[441,""],[442,""],[443,""],[444,""],[445,""],[446,""],[447,""],[448,""],[449,""],[450,"450"],[451,""],[452,""],[453,""],[454,""],[455,""],[456,""],[457,""],[458,""],[459,""],[460,""],[461,""],[462,""],[463,""],[464,""],[465,""],[466,""],[467,""],[468,""],[469,""],[470,""],[471,""],[472,""],[473,""],[474,""],[475,""],[476,""],[477,""],[478,""],[479,""],[480,""],[481,""],[482,""],[483,""],[484,""],[485,""],[486,""],[487,""],[488,""],[489,""],[490,""],[491,""],[492,""],[493,""],[494,""],[495,""],[496,""],[497,""],[498,""],[499,""],[500,"500"],[501,""],[502,""],[503,""],[504,""],[505,""],[506,""],[507,""],[508,""],[509,""],[510,""],[511,""],[512,""],[513,""],[514,""],[515,""],[516,""],[517,""],[518,""],[519,""],[520,""],[521,""],[522,""],[523,""],[524,""],[525,""],[526,""],[527,""],[528,""],[529,""],[530,""],[531,""],[532,""],[533,""],[534,""],[535,""],[536,""],[537,""],[538,""],[539,""],[540,""],[541,""],[542,""],[543,""],[544,""],[545,""],[546,""],[547,""],[548,""],[549,""],[550,"550"],[551,""],[552,""],[553,""],[554,""],[555,""],[556,""],[557,""],[558,""],[559,""],[560,""],[561,""],[562,""],[563,""],[564,""],[565,""],[566,""],[567,""],[568,""],[569,""],[570,""],[571,""],[572,""],[573,""],[574,""],[575,""],[576,""],[577,""],[578,""],[579,""],[580,""],[581,""],[582,""],[583,""],[584,""],[585,""],[586,""],[587,""],[588,""],[589,""],[590,""],[591,""],[592,""],[593,""],[594,""],[595,""],[596,""],[597,""],[598,""],[599,""],[600,"600"],[601,""],[602,""],[603,""],[604,""],[605,""],[606,""],[607,""],[608,""],[609,""],[610,""],[611,""],[612,""],[613,""],[614,""],[615,""],[616,""],[617,""],[618,""],[619,""],[620,""],[621,""],[622,""],[623,""],[624,""],[625,""],[626,""],[627,""],[628,""],[629,""],[630,""],[631,""],[632,""],[633,""],[634,""],[635,""],[636,""],[637,""],[638,""],[639,""],[640,""],[641,""],[642,""],[643,""],[644,""],[645,""],[646,""],[647,""],[648,""],[649,""],[650,"650"],[651,""],[652,""],[653,""],[654,""],[655,""],[656,""],[657,""],[658,""],[659,""],[660,""],[661,""],[662,""],[663,""],[664,""],[665,""],[666,""],[667,""],[668,""],[669,""],[670,""],[671,""]]
```

I've followed instructions from [jqplot docs](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Axis.ticks) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261043/jqplot-show-only-few-x-axis-ticks#18656405), but no success.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution (no idea whether it's a nice one or not but it's working). I had to edit  `jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js`, function **draw** `$.jqplot.CanvasFontRenderer.prototype.draw` (approx. line 406):

If the str parameter is an Array/Object second item must be used as tick label:

```
if (str instanceof Array) {
  str = str[1];
}
```